# How do i write inside of a txt file with c++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to insert the hardware id inside of a file called hardwareid2.txt, this is where the hardware id that i am extracting should be inserted, however it doesn't seem to be doing that and im not sure why, All the code seems to be doing is creating the file but not writing inside of the file. could someone help me debug this?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
std::string hwid = hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid;
int main()
{

    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL){
        std::ofstream hwidfile { "hardwareid2.txt" };
        hwidfile.open("hardwareid2.txt");
        hwidfile <<hwid;
        hwidfile.close();
        printf("Hardware GUID: %s\n",     hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
        printf("Hardware Profile: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileName);
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    getchar();



}
```

Comment: ALWAYS inspect the stream state after an IO transaction. If you don't check for failure that failure will be come a bug. In addition you almost never want to use a relative path for a file because assurances of where the working directory will be are weak.

Comment: Im sorry im new to C++ and have no clue what you just said, could you break it down a little simpler? What did i do wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: Recommendation: add to the question what the code seems to be doing instead and you'll hasten the debugging greatly. For example, if you can't find hardwareid2.txt after the stream is closed, odds are damn good you're looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: i couldn't find hardwareid2.txt at first but later found out it was being created in the directory in which the project is in.

Comment: Check 1: `hwidfile.open("hardwareid2.txt");` Use `hwidfile.is_open()` to make sure the file was successfully opened. If not, see if you can find out why and exit the program. Check 2: `hwidfile <<hwid;` does not confirm that `hwdi` really made it to the file. `if (hwidfile <<hwid)` will. As with open, if it writes, keep on going. If not, try to figure out what went wrong. If it's fixable, fix it and try again. If not, have the program spit out as much information about the failure as you can gather and and exit.

Comment: i did check 1 and it opened, however when i did check 2, nothing printed when i said if(hwidfile <<hwid) {printf("hwid successfully written");

Comment: hardware id is not empty and returns numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original code

```cpp
HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
std::string hwid = hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid;
```

The call to `GetCurrentHwProfile` that will load the system profile into `hwProfileInfo` is conspicuously absent between the definition of `hwProfileInfo` and its usage to initialize `hwid`. That means `hwProfileInfo;` is sitting in its default state, a big block of zeros because its been declared at global scope. `szHwProfileGuid` will be an empty, immediately null-terminated string, and that emptiness will be used to initialize `hwid`.

Much later `hwidfile <<hwid;` will write the empty string to the file stream. `printf("Hardware GUID: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);` prints the correct value because `hwProfileInfo` has been updated since `hwid` was initialized with the empty string.

Fix: Get rid of `hwid`. We don't need it.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo; // unless we have a very good reason, this should 
                                   // not be global
    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL)
    { // update info was a success. NOW we have a GUID and can do stuff with 
      // hwProfileInfo
        std::ofstream hwidfile { "hardwareid2.txt" };
        hwidfile.open("hardwareid2.txt");
        if (!(hwidfile << hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid)) 
        { // will fail if can't write for any reason, like file didn't open
            std::cout << "File write failed\n";
            return -1;
        }
        // hwidfile.close(); don't need this. hwidfile will auto-close when it exists scope
        printf("Hardware GUID: %s\n",     hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
        printf("Hardware Profile: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileName);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "GetCurrentHwProfile failed\n";
        return -1;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

But if we **do** need it, it must be updated after the GUID has been successfully gotten with `GetCurrentHwProfile`

```cpp
blah blah blah...
    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL)
    { 
        hwid = hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid;
        std::ofstream hwidfile { "hardwareid2.txt" };
...blah blah blah
```